# Calculate difference in property

Tags: arrays

I have converted a list of JSON objects to a generic list.
The Data structure on the items is as following

```
public class Person
{
    private string Name;
    private int Age;
    private string Weightloss;
}
```

The Weightloss string is of type "109-102" and I need to calculate how much each person has lost in weight since they signed up. I my examlpe it'd be 7. How to I, using LINQ Method syntax, calculate each weight loss (or gain). I assume I'll need to split up the string but I'm not really sure how

Comment: Why do you want to use LINQ? You're going to need to parse that string first (simple enough to not be troublesome - assuming the same format always), and LINQ isn't necessarily a magic utility to do that. Kinda seems like you're focusing on the wrong thing here.

Comment: Because it's part of a class assignment where we're learning to use LINQ but I can't wrap my head around this one.

Comment: So are you trying to get a certain subset of people from your `List<Person>` based on the calculation? Do you have other code that sorta outlines what you're after? It's a Language-Integrated **Query**, so I'm trying to sort out how your professor is intending you to use the query aspect. It seems a bit odd to me, but may not be odd at all, with  little context.

Comment: All I have is a list of persons with the above mentioned WeightLoss string. The assignment goes "What person had the biggest weightloss?" and I'm supposed to use LINQ to solve it. I literally have no idea how, otherwise I wouldn't have created an account here to ask the question. I am trying to get a single person as the result, the person with the biggest weightloss.

Comment: That makes a bit more sense, thanks. You should edit that into your question to clear things up a little. You'll still need to overcome the `Weightloss` parse/calculation first, which should be pretty trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather odd question, but if Linq is what you want, here is how one can go about it:

Create a function inside your class to calculate the weight difference:

```
public class Person
{
    //Constructor
    public Person(string name, int age, string weightLoss)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Weightloss = weightLoss;
    }

    public string Name;
    private int Age;
    private string Weightloss;

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the weight difference from the WeightLoss property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int GetWeightLoss()
    {
        //Get the values 
        var parts = Weightloss.Split('-')
            .Select(value => Convert.ToInt32(value))
            .ToArray();
        //Calculate the difference 
        var difference = parts[0] - parts[1];
        return difference;
    }
}
```

Not clean and I personally dislike it but it's homework so...

I added a constructor for initialization and changed the `Name` field to `public` so you can output it:

```
var list = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person("Juan", 30, "109-102"),
    new Person("Max", 35, "119-103"),
    new Person("John", 40, "109-105"),
};

//Figure out the largest loss
var maxLossPerson = list.OrderByDescending(p => p.GetWeightLoss()).First();
Console.WriteLine($"{maxLossPerson.Name} lost the most with {maxLossPerson.GetWeightLoss()} pound(s)");
```

Output:

> > Max lost the most with 16 pound(s)

Answer (score 0):

You're either going to use a string split or a regular expression.
Assuming your string is always formatted "`Weight1`-`Weight2`", a string split would be fairly simple:

```cs
public int[] ParseWeights(string weightString) {
    var weights = weightString.Split('-');
    var beginningWeight = Convert.ToInt32(weights[0]);
    var endingWeight = Convert.ToInt32(weights[1]);
    return new int[] {beginningWeight, endingWeight};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another property to `Person`:

```
public class Person
{
    private string Name;
    private int Age;
    private string Weightloss;

    public int WeightLost
    {
        get
        {
              int[] values = Weightloss.Split('-').Select(i => int.Parse(i)).ToArray();
              return values[0] - values[1];
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look for a even more Linq way, you can use the follow way:

```
    private string Weightloss;

    public int WeightLossInt => Weightloss
        .Split('-')
        .Select((value, index) => index == 0 ? int.Parse(value) : -int.Parse(value))
        .Sum();
}
```